# How to preg_match a directory then return that directory

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to check for a directory that matches `.core*` and return it as a string.

Example: If the directory name is `.core-alpha`, then return `.core-alpha` as a string. Or, if the found directory is `.core-1-rc1`, return that as the string.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
$str = '.core/';
$core = preg_match('.core.', $str);

define('ROOT_DIR', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) .'/');

require_once(ROOT_DIR . $core . '/lib/app.php');
$app = new App();
```

That just returns an integer - i.e.:

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/1/lib/app.php
```

Any help would be appreciated - Thnx

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `.core.*` instead of just `.core.`?

Comment: And according to [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), it returns a boolean.

Comment: I had originally used the `*` but it threw an error for using it

Comment: In link above example#3 might help you with your problem

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` returns a 1 or 0, NOT the match. So just test the return value:

```
$str = '.core/';
if (preg_match('/^\.core.*/', $str)) {
    $core = $str;
}
```

Check the first example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: I upped it because it is a start.  The missing portion as in my question: `...if the found directory is .core-1-rc1, return that as the string.` ..meaning return the match similar to `.core**`

Comment: It should return it. If you want the trailing slash knocked off, you can just use `$core = rtrim($str, '/');`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have a missing parameter. receiver of matched value should be passed by reference.

can you try this

```
$str = '.core/';
   if (preg_match('/^\.core.*/', $str, $core)) {
      echo $core[0];
   }
   else
   {
      echo "No Match Found."
   }
```

Comment: The optional third parameter is pointless here as his regex has no subpatterns.

Comment: got it. thanks :)

I was fixated on use $core on the answer. anyway, this should help him solve the prob.